# C# Visual Studio 2012 Speech to textBox1

Tags: c#, microsoft-speech-api

I got a problem with the Speech API. I'm working with commands, thats working fine, but when I want the speech to be seen in the textBox1 it wont show it.

This is the code I need help with. Im working with a switch case. I tried several if statement, but none works.

```
case "listen":
                    AI.Speak("I am listening");
                    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " " + e.Result.Text.ToString();
                    break;
```

Each time I say listen, only 'listen'  comes visible in the textBox

Here is the full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Web;
using WindowsMicrophoneMuteLibrary;
using TweetSharp;
/*                                          
 *                                          
 *                                         
 *  
 *                                          
 * 
 */

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SpeechRecognitionEngine sRecognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        SpeechSynthesizer AI = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        WindowsMicMute micMute = new WindowsMicMute();
        TwitterService twitter = new TwitterService("--", "--", "--", "--");
        //string QEvent;
        //string ProcWindow;
        //double timer = 10;
        //int count = 1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sRecognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            sRecognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\Bibliotheek\Mijn Documenten\Commands.txt")))));
            sRecognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(rSpeechRecognized);
            sRecognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            // LAAD COMMANDS BIJ START-UP
            string[] commands = (File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\Bibliotheek\Mijn Documenten\Commands.txt"));
            lstCommands.Items.Clear();
            lstCommands.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.None;
            foreach (string command in commands)
            {
                lstCommands.Items.Add(command);
            }
        }

        void rSpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            int ranNum = rnd.Next(1, 10);
            string speech = e.Result.Text;
            switch (speech)
            {
                // GROETEN
                case "hello":                               // ALS "hello" WORDT INGESPROKEN IN DE MICROFOON
                    if (ranNum <= 3)                         
                    {
                        AI.Speak("Hello Sir");          // ALS RANDOM NUMMER < 5 IS = "hello sir"
                    }
                    else if (ranNum >= 4 && ranNum <= 6)                    
                    {
                        AI.Speak("Greetings");          // ALS RANDOM NUMMER >= 5 IS = "greetings"
                    }
                    else if (ranNum >= 7)
                    {
                        AI.Speak("Good day to you");
                    }
                    break;
                case "AI":                              // ALS "AI" WORDT INGESPROKEN IN DE MICROFOON
                    if (ranNum <= 4)                         
                    {
                        AI.Speak("Yes Sir");            // ALS RANDOM NUMMER < 5 IS = "yes sir"
                    }
                    else if (ranNum >= 5)                   
                    {
                        AI.Speak("Yes?");               // ALS RANDOM NUMMER >= 5 IS = "yes?"
                    }
                    break;

                // SLUIT
                case "exit program":                        // ALS "exit program" WORDT INGESPROKEN IN DE MICROFOON
                    AI.Speak("Until next time");        
                    this.Close();                                // APPLICATIE WORDT GESLOTEN
                    break;

                // WEBSITES
                case "open google":                         // ALS "open google" WORDT INGESPROKEN IN DE MICROFOON
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.nl");   // GOOGLE WORDT GEOPEND
                    break;
                case "open youtube":                        // ALS "open youtube" WORDT INGESPROKEN IN DE MICROFOON
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions"); // YOUTUBE WORDT GEOPEND
                    break;
                case "open tweakers":                        // ALS "tweakers" WORDT INGESPROKEN IN DE MICROFOON
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://tweakers.net/"); // TWEAKERS WORDT GEOPEND
                    break;

                // PROGRAMMA'S
                case "run guild wars":                      // ALS "run guild wars" WORDT INGESPROKEN IN DE MICROFOON
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("D:\\Entertainment\\Guild Wars 2\\Gw2.exe");   // GUILD WARS 2 WORDT GEOPEND
                    AI.Speak("Loading program");
                    break;

                // GEGEVENS VAN DE DAG
                case "whats the time":                     // ALS "what time is it" WORDT INGESPROKEN IN DE MICROFOON
                    AI.Speak(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"));           // TIJD VAN DE DAG WORDT VERTELD
                    break;
                case "whats the day":                      // ALS "what day is it" WORDT INGESPROKEN IN DE MICROFOON
                    AI.Speak(DateTime.Today.ToString("dddd"));          // DAG VAN VANDAAG WORDT VERTELD
                    break;
                case "whats the date":                      // ALS "whats the date" WORDT INGESPROKEN IN DE MICROFOON
                    AI.Speak(DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"));   // DATUM VAN VANDAAG WORDT VERTELD
                    break;

                // ANDERE COMMANDS
                case "go fullscreen":                       // ALS "go fullscreen" WORDT INGESPROKEN IN DE MICROFOON
                    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                    WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                    TopMost = true;
                    AI.Speak("Going into fullscreen mode");
                    break;
                case "exit fullscreen":                     // ALS "exit fullscreen" WORDT INGESPROKEN IN DE MICROFOON
                    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
                    WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                    TopMost = false;
                    AI.Speak("Exiting fullscreen mode");
                    break;

                // TWITTER
                case "post on twitter":
                    if (listBox1.Visible == true)
                    {
                        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(89, 163);
                        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(18, 166);
                    }
                    textBox1.Visible = true;
                    label1.Visible = true;
                    break;
                case "post":
                    if (textBox1.Visible == false)
                    {
                        AI.Speak("say post on twitter first");
                    }
                    else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text.Trim()))
                    {
                        AI.Speak("you will have to write down something");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        twitter.SendTweet(new SendTweetOptions() { Status = textBox1.Text });
                        AI.Speak("Your tweet has been posted");
                        textBox1.Clear();
                    }
                    break;
                case "clear post":
                    textBox1.Visible = false;
                    label1.Visible = false;
                    break;
                case "show tweets":
                    listBox1.Visible = true;
                    label2.Visible = true;
                    if (textBox1.Visible == true)
                    {
                        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(89, 163);
                        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(18, 166);
                    }
                    listBox1.Visible = true;
                    label2.Visible = true;
                    listBox1.Items.Clear();
                    var getTweets = twitter.ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline(new ListTweetsOnHomeTimelineOptions() { Count = 10 });
                    foreach (var tweets in getTweets)
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(tweets.Text);
                    }
                    break;
                case "clear tweets":
                    listBox1.Visible = false;
                    label2.Visible = false;
                    this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(89, 9);
                    this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(18, 12);
                    break;
                case "update tweets":
                    if (listBox1.Visible == false)
                    {
                        AI.Speak("I cant update without getting the tweets first");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Clear();
                        var update = twitter.ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline(new ListTweetsOnHomeTimelineOptions() { Count = 10 });
                        foreach (var tweets in update)
                        {
                            listBox1.Items.Add(tweets.Text);
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                **case "listen":
                    AI.Speak("I am listening");
                    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " " + e.Result.Text.ToString();
                    break;**


                /*
                case "show commands":
                    string[] commands = (File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\Bibliotheek\Mijn Documenten\Commands.txt"));
                    JARVIS.Speak("Very well");
                    lstCommands.Items.Clear();
                    lstCommands.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.None;
                    lstCommands.Visible = true;
                    foreach (string command in commands)
                    {
                        lstCommands.Items.Add(command);
                    }
                    break;
                case "hide commands":
                    lstCommands.Visible = false;
                    break;
                 */
            }
        }

        private void lstCommands_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnMic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnMic.Text == "Mute")
            {
                btnMic.Text = "Unmute";
                micMute.MuteMic();
                AI.Speak("Muted");
            }
            else if (btnMic.Text == "Unmute")
            {
                btnMic.Text = "Mute";
                micMute.UnMuteMic();
                AI.Speak("Unmuted");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I need help with this piece of the code:

```
case "listen":
                    AI.Speak("I am listening");
                    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " " + e.Result.Text.ToString();
                    break;
```

When I say 'listen', AI follows up with "I am listening". After that it should be placing the text im saying into the microphone in the textbox1, but it doesnt. It only places 'listen'  in it.

Everything else works fine!

Comment: That's a lot of code. Please edit your question down to a succinct example of your problem.

Comment: Isn't `e.Result.Text.ToString()` already set, and you would need to call something to capture speech at that point?

Answer (score 1):

```
case "listen":
    AI.Speak("I am listening");
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " " + e.Result.Text.ToString();
    break;
```

`e.Result` will contains only the result obtained when the user said "Listen".
You need to actually *listen* the user again after you make the AI said "I am listening".

```
case "listen":
    AI.Speak("I am listening");
    var result = sRecognizer.Recognize();
    textBox1.Text += " " + result.Text;
    break;
```

Comment: Im getting this error now: Cannot perform this operation while the recognizer is doing recognition. So the recognizer is already active when I said listen, so does this means I dont need to call it again, right.

Comment: That's because you haven't finished handling current speech("Listen").  You will have to change the flow of the program to solve that. You can save the last speech command and if the last speech command is 'listen' then proceed to write the current result into the text box. Or break the current flow and use an infinite loop to host the main flow and branch as needed.

Answer (score 0):

How quickly are you saying 'Listen'? <strike>I suspect your issue is the speech API is only looking for the first 'Listen' then it's busy parsing data while you say 'Listen' again.</strike> I believe the other answer addressed this piece correctly - once you recognize the speech text, you must call recognize again.

Try speaking less quickly, or saying listen (wait for command to parse) then listen again. Does it work as expected?

You might want to investigate [using asych methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.recognizeasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[EDIT]
After you changed your description, try this:

```
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " " + speech;
```

Comment: No matte rwhat I do, I am getting the: Cannot perform this operation while the recognizer is doing recognition; when I put a var in there.